# Can modify object detection true positive define(IOU)?

Tags: object-detection, metrics, object-detection-api

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOhvj.jpg)

I met a problem about object detection metric,like image1,

The red boxes are ground truth, the black box is predict box, and the prediction class is correct.
If I use IOU method, all prediction boxes output false positive! But in my case, I hope to predict true positive.

Does any method can solve this problem? By the way, Don't consider modifying ground truth boxes.